# Customer dropdown click using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have drop down which is basically a `div` that is displayed in a block, When I click on a button. Each value/item in a drop down is `div`. Dropdown value is something like this `"Click to view report <img-help>"`. Now my question is when i try to open the drop down and click on a item, i see that sometime `<img-help>` is clicked and the test is failing as clicking on image will open a help window and it is not actually selecting the item in the dropdown. How can avoid this and just click on the text?

I basically click on the button and parse through the list and then click on the value that matches on what I want to click using Selenium Java api.

**updating the code that i am trying to click** I am trying to click  `"XXXXXXXYYYYYYXXXXXX"`  in the div. which will refresh the page with new data.

Also wanted to mention that I am doing this in IE7. Firefox seems to be working fine.

```
<div class="mstrListBlockItemSelected" title="Evaluate charges to identify potential for improvement.">
<div class="mstrListBlockItemName" style="padding-left: 25px;">
    XXXXXXXYYYYYYXXXXXX
<span style="width: 4px;"/>
<img style="width: 16px; height: 16px; cursor: pointer;" alt="Help" src="../plugins/custom/images/help.gif"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code chunk?

Comment: Your selenium code that you tried?

Comment: Try this -> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.mstrListBlockItemSelected div.mstrListBlockItemName")).click()

Comment: @Purus I have common function where i pass xpath...so if i change that to CSS i have to change the code..do you have any other suggestion please? My selenium code is simple i just get all the div and text of the div, loop through it and if my passing value matches, it will click the value.

Comment: why dont you re do the code were you only pass a By value, there it wouldn't matter if you sent a xpath or a cssSelector

Comment: You can just change the CSS Selector to equivalen Xpath in that case.